# iPad webapp: fixed footer und zoomable content

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, zooming, footer

I'm working on a webapp which will have a fixed footer, but the content remains zoomable, similar to google maps.

I've tried it with jquery mobile but it does not work as desired.

If nothing works, I must write my own completely self-zoom new, but I do not want.

Excuse my bad english. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

That is the first thing I would try. Fixed or absolute positions are wired within the mobile safari, because when scrolling or zooming not page is moved, the viewport is instead. Once I had a similar problem and tried [this](http://cubiq.org/iscroll), what tries to fix this, but I wasn't lucky with my problem. Maybe it helps you

good luck…